# SQL query to remove a particular string from a varchar(100) sentence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column called "Sentence varchar (100)".
It contains the data as:

```
"first name, last name : is Activated on 01/01/2017 "
"first name, last name : is Downloaded on 01/01/2017 "
"first name, last name : is Deleted on 01/01/2017 "
"first name, last name : is Deactivated on 01/01/
"first name, last name : is Born on 01/01/2017 "
```

Here I would like to write an SQL query to show the every string as:

"first name, last name : is Activated" 
"first name, last name : is Born"

I want to remove the string from "on date...... so".

How can I write an SQL Server query for this?

Answer (score 5):

You are lucky, because the part of the string you want to remove is of fixed length.  So, you can just do:

```
select left(sentence, len(sentence) - 14)
```

The "14" is the length of `' on dd/mm/yyyy'`.

Comment: Unless the person's first and last name combine to be 70 characters or more. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Normalized table, and very difficult to use because of that.

You shoud have a table like

```
Event: Id | firstName | lastName | date | eventTypeId
```

Where `EventType` represents `Activated`, `Downloaded`, `Deleted`, with 2 columns:

```
EventType: Id | eventName
```

Then, you van reconstruct your data with:

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstName," , ",lastName," : is ",EventType.eventName," on ",date) 
    FROM EVENT
    JOIN EventType ON EventType.id=Event.eventTypeId
```

Or, to get the data without the date:

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstName," , ",lastName," : is ",EventType.eventName) 
    FROM EVENT
    JOIN EventType ON EventType.id=Event.eventTypeId
```

Comment: The best solution so far

Answer (score 0):

You could use replace

```
select  REPLACE(Sentence , 'Activated', 'Born')
from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like: `UPDATE Table SET Sentence = SUBSTR(Sentence, 0, LOCATE(' on ', Sentence))`

Comment: This is clearly tagged with sql server. Your answer is using mysql functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works.

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @yourdata TABLE (sentence varchar(100));
INSERT @yourdata VALUES 

('first name, last name : is Activated on 01/01/2017'),
('first name, last name : is Downloaded on 01/01/2017'),
('first name, last name : is Deleted on 01/01/2017'),
('first name, last name : is Deactivated on 01/01/'),
('first name, last name : is Born on 01/01/2017');

--Solution
SELECT sentenceNew = SUBSTRING(sentence, 1, PATINDEX('% on [0-9][0-9]/%', sentence)-1)
FROM @yourdata;
```

Results:

```
-----------------------------------------
first name, last name : is Activated
first name, last name : is Downloaded
first name, last name : is Deleted
first name, last name : is Deactivated
first name, last name : is Born
```